# Invoking a combobox's selected folder(C#)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, combobox

I am using two comboboxes, in which 1st box will display folders in the specified location from that drop down list i will be selecting the necessary folder, so after selection the second combobox should list only the files depending on the 1st box's selected folder.(NOTE:Am not working with database, just accessing computers folder).  Am working with visual studio 2013 in C#. Thanks in advance.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\jeeva\Desktop\1234");
DirectoryInfo[] folders = di.GetDirectories(); 
comboBox1.DataSource = folders; 
string selected =comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
String fullpath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\jeeva\Desktop\1234", selected);
DirectoryInfo di1 = new DirectoryInfo(fullpath); 
DirectoryInfo[] folders1 = di1.GetDirectories(); 
comboBox2.DataSource = folders1
```

Comment: Please share what have you tried?

Comment: windows forms or WPF?

Comment: WINDOWS FORMS @Uthistran S

Comment: DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\jeeva\Desktop\1234");
            DirectoryInfo[] folders = di.GetDirectories();
            comboBox1.DataSource = folders;
            string selected =comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            String fullpath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\jeeva\Desktop\1234", selected);
            DirectoryInfo di1 = new DirectoryInfo(fullpath);
            DirectoryInfo[] folders1 = di1.GetDirectories();
            comboBox2.DataSource = folders1;

Comment: DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\jeeva\Desktop\1234");
            DirectoryInfo[] folders = di.GetDirectories();
            comboBox1.DataSource = folders;
            string selected =comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            String fullpath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\jeeva\Desktop\1234", selected);
            DirectoryInfo di1 = new DirectoryInfo(fullpath);
            DirectoryInfo[] folders1 = di1.GetDirectories();
            comboBox2.DataSource = folders1;                                              @RichaGarg

Comment: please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39270668/edit) button below your post

Comment: What result you are getting with this?

Comment: Combobox1 displays the specified folders and no data found in comb0box2 @RichaGarg

Comment: it is because you need to separate the 2 steps of loading the folders and selecting an item. The user needs the time to choose. This does not happen in your code. After the `comboBox1` is populated you already try to access the selected item which has not happened yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done basically in 2 steps. You just need to separate them in your code.

1) get the folders into your combobox (may be already in the constructor of the Form):

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\jeeva\Desktop\1234");
DirectoryInfo[] folders = di.GetDirectories(); 
comboBox1.DataSource = folders;
```

2) double click `comboBox1` in the designer. This will create an event which is triggered when the user selects an item. Inside it you can then get all the subfolders and give them as `DataSource` to the `ComboBox` which shall display them.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       

    string selected =comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
    String fullpath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\jeeva\Desktop\1234", selected);
    DirectoryInfo di1 = new DirectoryInfo(fullpath); 
    DirectoryInfo[] folders1 = di1.GetDirectories(); 
    comboBox2.DataSource = folders1     
}
```

Comment: Am not accessing files in combobox2 i need to access subfolders from the selected folder from combobox1 @Mong Zhu

Comment: @warriors my mistake, I changed it, but the code is taken from your example, so it should do the trick

Comment: @warriors you should change this line in your question: **"so after selection the second combobox should list only the files depending on the 1st box's selected folder"**, it might lead to confusion

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Mong Zhu, mastering codes I salute @Mong Zhu

Comment: @warriors glad I could help. Best way to say thank you on StackOverflo is to accept and/or upvote helpful answers. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Directory.GetFiles("folderName")` method to populate your second combobox. `Directory` class resides in `System.IO` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

On the Onchange event of Combobox1:

```
ComboBox2.dataSource = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(ComboBox1.SelectedText)
```

This should populate all the files in Combobox2

Comment: Please provide some more information like what technology you are using  or what is your problem or what are your requirement with this code.

Comment: `ComboBox1.SelectedText` will yield an empty string. This solution will not work.

Comment: I Tried with the below code but the result was negative,              
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\jeeva\Desktop\1234");
            DirectoryInfo[] folders = di.GetDirectories();
            comboBox1.DataSource = folders;
          
            comboBox2.DataSource = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(comboBox1.SelectedText); @karthi keyan

Answer (score 0):

You can get the folder list by something like this:

```
DirectoryInfo obj = new DirectoryInfo("E:\\");//you can set your directory     path here
DirectoryInfo[] folders = obj.GetDirectories();
YourDirCombo.DataSource = folders ;
```

You probably have a method listening to your first combo changes:

```
private void YourDirCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

now in this you can get the files of the selected folder:

```
string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(YourDirCombo.SelectedValue);
YourFileCombo.DataSource = fileEntries;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following can be optimized and generalized in several different ways - I'm doing it "long hand" to give you the most information possible.

```
private void initializeComboBoxes()
    {
        ComboBox c = new ComboBox();
        c.Name = "cbx_One";
        c.Items.Add("Select a File");
        foreach(string direc in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"PathToYourFiles"))
        {
            c.Items.Add(direc);
        }
        c.SelectedIndex = 0;
        c.SelectedIndexChanged += loadComboBox2;
        Controls.Add(c);
        ComboBox c1 = new ComboBox();
        c1.Name = "cbx_Two";
        c1.Items.Add("Waiting for file selection");
        c1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        c1.SelectedIndexChanged += loadFile;
        Controls.Add(c1);
        areComboBoxesUpdating = false;
    }
    bool areComboBoxesUpdating = true;
    protected void loadComboBox2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!areComboBoxesUpdating)
        {
            ComboBox c1 = sender as ComboBox;
            ComboBox c2 = Controls.Find("cbx_Two", true)[0] as ComboBox;
            c2.Items.Clear();
            if (c1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                c2.Items.Add("Waiting for file selection");
            }
            else
            {
                c2.Items.Add("Please select a file");
                //assuming c1 is the list of directories
                foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(c1.SelectedItem.ToString()))
                {
                    c2.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(c1.SelectedItem.ToString()));
                }
            }
            areComboBoxesUpdating = true;
            c2.SelectedIndex = 0;
            areComboBoxesUpdating = false;
        }
    }
    protected void loadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //a selection has been made from the second box - you have directory in box1 and filename in box2
        ComboBox c = sender as ComboBox;
        if (c.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            string directory = ((ComboBox)Controls.Find("cbx_One", true)[0]).SelectedItem.ToString();
            string file = c.SelectedItem.ToString();
            //do something
        }
    }
```